# jQuery - image src characters being replaced by symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, magento

Im using a module for Magento 2 which adds a zoom feature to product pages, but for some reason in the src for the image it needs to use to zoom random symbols are being added.

[http://magento.local:8080/pub/media/catalog/productಬhe�97d34b4208afe58d346643e2db/r/i/riccardo-dining-table-90cm-grey-knightsbridge-shimmer-grey_5__1.jpg](http://magento.local:8080/pub/media/catalog/product%E0%B2%AChe%EF%BF%BD97d34b4208afe58d346643e2db/r/i/riccardo-dining-table-90cm-grey-knightsbridge-shimmer-grey_5__1.jpg)

**ಬhe�** This bit

I have traced where the symbols are coming from but am confused as to why they are being added.

```
if(self.options.zoomType == "inner") {
    self.zoomWindow.css({ backgroundImage: "url('" + self.imageSrc + "')" }); //the symbols are being added here.
}
```

In this section self.imageSrc is equal to: "http://magento.local:8080/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\2e967597d34b4208afe58d346643e2db\/i/m/img_8820-1_5.png"

But after that bit of code applying the background image runs the src changes to:
"http://magento.local:8080/pub/media/catalog/productಬhe�97d34b4208afe58d346643e2db/i/m/img_8820-1_5.png"

Comment: You probably need to escape `self.imageSrc`

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah, that was it! Thanks so much